# How do i do an Embedded pages for my discord bot?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

How do i embed pages?? i have seen people used them for their bots but I'm not sure how to do it. something like in this picture. [image]

Comment: You can do an awaitReaction and then edit the embed. There's probably better ways to do this, but its just the first thing that comes to mind

Answer (score 0):

This isn't embedded a page, its an embed object.

Look at https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html for more information